# 550 operation not permitted using FTP

Tags: ftp

I'm using FTP to manage some files on a site I run but keep seeing this (truncated) error log:

```
Command:    DELE calendarpermission.php
Response:   550 calendarpermission.php: Operation not permitted
[...]
Command:    DELE button_down.gif
Response:   550 button_down.gif: Operation not permitted
Command:    CWD /domains/example.com/public_html/admincp
Response:   250 CWD command successful
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/domains/example.com/public_html/admincp" is the current directory
Command:    RMD control_examples
Response:   550 control_examples: Operation not permitted
Command:    CWD /domains/example.com/public_html
Response:   250 CWD command successful
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/domains/example.com/public_html" is the current directory
Command:    RMD admincp
Response:   550 admincp: Operation not permitted
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (122,155,5,50,138,244).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for MLSD
Response:   226 Transfer complete
Status: Directory listing successful
Status: Set permissions of '/domains/example.com/public_html/admincp' to '777'
Command:    SITE CHMOD 777 admincp
Response:   550 CHMOD 777 admincp: Operation not permitted
```

What do I do to solve this?

Comment: 550 is FTP's "No, I can't do that". That probably means you don't have read access to the files, or they don't exist.

Comment: if you are using vsftpd, there is a flag set in the vsftpd.conf file to prevent writing even if the permissions are set for writing access.

Answer (score 2):

If

```
Command:    SITE CHMOD 777 admincp
Response:   550 CHMOD 777 admincp: Operation not permitted
```

occurs then it means that you have absolutely no permissions to do that, you should resolve this problem with your hosting so that they can give your permissions; maybe that folder is has the purpose to stay?

Comment: resert ownwer in direct admin?

Comment: @monkey this is a very general permissions problem. No knowing what kind of environment you're working with, we can't know what needs to be done on your end to fix it. If you have a "reset owners" function in your back-end, that *might* be the way to go

Answer (score 1):

`/domains/example.com/public_html/admincp` may be owned by root. It may have been created by PHP and that would be why it is owned by root. Regardless, the user you logged into through ftp isn't allowed to modify the permissions of that file (or it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1):

```
Command:    SITE CHMOD 777 admincp
Response:   550 CHMOD 777 admincp: Operation not permitted
```

Means that the the FTP user does not own the file/folder you're trying to chown. They may be in the same group and have full access to the file, but only the owner can chmod a file (or root/sudo). To resolve this you need to own the file (delete + recreate from backup not perserving  owners/rights may work)

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this isn't quite the same scenario, however I can confirm that copying the contents to the clipboard, and creating a new file on ftp, then pasting the clipboard contents to the new file  worked for me to restore writability to .htaccess.